# What parameters are sent by Telerik's RadClientDataSource control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have a RadClientDataSource in an aspx page for which EnableServerPaging, EnableServerSorting, EnableServerFiltering are all set to true in the markup for RadClientDataSource.

**Question**

What parameters will be passed by RadClientDataSource control to server-side web service in such a situation? I checked the documentation for RadClientDataSource at https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/clientdatasource/service-configuration but there is no mention of what standard parameters RadClientDataSource passes to server-side.

```
<telerik:RadClientDataSource runat="server" ID="RadClientDataSource1" EnableServerPaging="true" AllowPaging="true" 
               EnableServerFiltering="True" EnableServerSorting="true">
<DataSource>
    <WebServiceDataSourceSettings>
        <Select Url="api/emplist/GetTaskList" RequestType="Get" DataType="JSON" EnableCaching="false"/>
    </WebServiceDataSourceSettings>
</DataSource>
</telerik:RadClientDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be in the method parameters like so:

public static object GetTaskList(int? take = null, int? skip = null, int? page = null, int? pageSize = null)